# Site timeout with cookie set before new deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

Consider the following scenario:

A user logs in to my webapplication, successfully. Browses around for 1 minute then closes the browser tab. (The cookie has been set, from loggin in).

Right after, I deploy a new update to the webapplication.
The user now visits the site again, just after deployment.
The site times out.

The timeout occurs until the browser releases the cookie.

If the user deletes the cookie, the user goes directly to the login page, without hassle.

I've tried finding out whats going on.

The problem seems to occur during decryption of the authentication ticket.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt( authCookie.Value );
```

In `global.asax` `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest`

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get past this.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE:

I had a theory based on the MachineKey not being set explicitly, which means that when the AppPool recycles, the MachineKey changes.

Setting MachineKey fixed my issue.

Comment: You say the problem is on the Decrypt line - does this throw an exception? If so, what?

Comment: @David_001 It doesn't. If it did, I would have posted it -ofcourse.
If i put a breakpoint on it, it breaks, if I continue it disregards breakpoints further down the code.

Comment: Odd. I don't suppose there are any events posted into the WIndows Events log on the web server? Also, you say you set the machine key - I assume you set the decryptionKey property of the machine key within web.config?

Comment: Eventviewer had an earlier error regarding forms ticket being invalid (from before machinekey) - it turned out, i ALSO had an issue with some async timeout - so the machinekey basically fixed the issue, but promoted another issue

Comment: I will accept the machinekey answer from you, if you want the points :) since you pointed me in the right direction with the event viewer and explicitly asking about the machinekey